# RabbitMQ server won't start anymore after assigning username/password

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, erlang, devops, centos7

I installed a rabbitmq server and it was active and running fine until I entered:

echo "[{loopback_users, []}]}]." > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config

I also assigned a username and password and also assigned the user as administrator. I tried to restart the server after that and it wouldn't restart. Checked the status and it was no longer running. Any idea what I did wrong? Still a rookie, any tips would be great.

```
    [root@rmq01 ~]# systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service -l
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-12 05:47:22 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 1807 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7026 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7026 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Standing by"

Aug 12 05:47:22 rmq01 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 12 05:47:22 rmq01 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Aug 12 05:47:22 rmq01 systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Aug 12 05:47:22 rmq01 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
```

I'm sure the answer is right in front of me but I can't seem to pin point it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use the new format file config:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.8.x/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example

```
## Related doc guide: https://rabbitmq.com/access-control.html.

## The default "guest" user is only permitted to access the server
## via a loopback interface (e.g. localhost).
## {loopback_users, [<<"guest">>]},
##
# loopback_users.guest = true
```